# Select a specific row in large (5000+ rows) webtable

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In my Application, There is a dynamic web table (approx. 5000 rows) displayed on one page. My requirement is to select a specific element (by clicking on radio button against that row) and proceed for further action. With traditional approach of reading data from webtable, it takes approximately 2 minutes to read each row and then column data, followed by comparison of specific data that I need to select.

Manually this can be quickly done by *Find option (‘CTRL+F’ )* on that page. 
Please suggest me if there is any time efficient way to perform this action.
Feel free to let me know if you need more clarification on this question.[image: sample table data]

```
<tr class="ledgerBackground1">
   <td class="ledger">
      <input type="radio" value="9001" name="agent" />
   </td>
   <td class="ledger">9001</td>
   <td class="ledger">Michel</td>
   <td class="ledger">user</td>
   <td class="ledger">10/12/16</td>
</tr>
<tr class="ledgerBackground1">
   <td class="ledger">
      <input type="radio" value="9004" name="agent" />
   </td>
   <td class="ledger">9004</td>
   <td class="ledger">Kerry</td>
   <td class="ledger">user</td>
   <td class="ledger">10/12/16</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I don't suppose you can post a link to the page? Can you at least give us some sample rows and tell us what you need to look for? You might be able to create an XPath that would find it fairly quickly depending on the HTML and what you are looking for.

Comment: Jeff - Added the rows for more clarity. In that say I need to select the row 9001. For that I am traversing the complete web table, than perform comparison to find which row contains the ID 9001.   To Create xpath, I need to know exactly which row have the ID that I am look for.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML.

Comment: Jeff- I have added the html for the last 2 rows. This has modified data with similar schema. Can't include the actual code because of compliance issue. Few additional details,       Xpath for radio button corresponding to 9001: html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[8095]/td[1]/input

Comment: Xpath for radio button corresponding to 9004: html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[8096]/td[1]/input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your HTML, you want to find a `TD` with class `ledger` that contains "9001" (or whatever text). Once we locate that element we want to find it's previous sibling that contains an `INPUT`. We can do that with the XPath below.

```
//td[@class='ledger'][text()='9001']/preceding-sibling::td/input
```

You didn't specify a language so the code below is Java but it should be easily adaptable to whatever language you use.

```
String searchText = "9001";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='ledger'][text()='" + searchText + "']/preceding-sibling::td/input")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff. This is really helpful.. specially the Axes "Preceding-siblings".

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you found this answer userful, please upvote it. If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer. Thanks!